# Reference request for text containing proof of quadratic reciprocity law over function fields

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-reciprocity

While I have found a number of sources online (e.g. [this)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-09/S0002-9939-08-09327-1/S0002-9939-08-09327-1.pdf) that prove the law of quadratic reciprocity for polynomials over finite fields, I am looking for a *book* on the subject or at least has a section dedicated to the topic. Ideally, there would be some exposition and motivation for the theorem.

Comment: Decomposition groups and such for ideals over a global field are treated pretty generally in most texts, eg. Weil's *Basic Number Theory* or Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, though I don't have the latter in front of me at the moment to confirm that he explicitly treats both cases at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that Chapter 3 of "Number Theory in Function Fields" of Michael Rosen might be what you're looking for, especially Theorem 3.3 there. Perhaps it is a bit more general than just quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Seconding this. That's a great book!

Comment: Quoting from the Forward: "The first four chapters of this book are devoted to illustrating this by presenting, for example, analogues of the little theorems of Fermat and Euler, Wilson's theorem, **quadratic** (and higher) **reciprocity**, the prime number theorem, and Dirichlet's theorem on primes in an arithmetic progression."

Comment: @hardmath well that's about as spot on as I could ask for.